# Ubuntu 19.10, Thunderbird 68 can't login with IMAP but POP OK

Tags: login, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I'm relatively new to Linux, but when I want to add my email account to Thunderbird with IMAP access, the Google Mail sign in popup window says "Unable to login at server. Probably wrong configuration, username or password."

I tried setting up on Gmail access for less secure apps, and have two phase login on, which did not solve the problem.

I have used Thunderbird with this Gmail account on Windows for many years without any problems.

How may I troubleshoot and resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m new to ubuntu myself and I’m having the same problem: when I try to add google account the web login prompt comes up, I can log in with my password and 2fa and when I click allow Tunderbird it gets me back to Thunderbird with an error saying ”Unable to login at server. Probably wrong configuration, username or password.“
I was able to replicate the issue in Ubuntu 18.04 as well!
The issue seems to be with OAuth2 and has been fixed in Thunderbird 68.2.1: https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/68.2.1/releasenotes/ unfortunately Ubuntu 19.10 shipped with 68.1.2 :(

As a **work-around** I’m using 68.2.2 downloaded as a tarball from thunderbird website and everything works absolutely fine. As a test you can download it from https://www.thunderbird.net , un-archive it and run the `thunderbird` executable.

Question to Ubuntu veterans: what can we do to get version 68.2.1/2 included in the official repo? File a bug report?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, i had to download the new version from https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/ then it worked, except it is not a proper installation that is merged with the system. You have an icon on the desktop but not integrated. So I cant make a launcher icon in the panels.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-thunderbird-linux
It seems the older versions are not updating and the older versions don't like Google mail, I had the same problem at work on a windows machine. I had to download the new version manually as it didn't update automatically.

Comment: Looks like version 68.2.2 is available in the snap store which will integrate very nicley with the system. You can install it from the edge branch: 
`sudo snap install thunderbird --edge`

Comment: Thanks, works great, why don't they update the software Center? Very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this:

Install Thunderbird Email Client in Linux
To install Thunderbird from the default system repositories issue:

`$ sudo apt-get install thunderbird`   [On Ubuntu based systems]
`$ dnf install thunderbird`            [On Fedora based systems]
As I said, installing from default repositories will give you older version of Thunderbird. If you want to install most recent version of Mozilla Thunderbird, you can use the PPA maintained by the Mozilla team.

Use CTRL + ALT + T from the desktop to open terminal and add the Thunderbird repository under Ubuntu and its derivatives.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
Next, update the system software packages using update command.

$ sudo apt-get update
```

Once you've updated the system, install it using the following command.

```
$ sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

Comment: I think this works not because it's a new version but because it wipes out some sort of config file...

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and find solution when I changed Authentication method from: 0Auth2 to Normal password:

[image]